# jQuery UI Datepicker doesn't take options properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("form").submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  for (var i=1;i<=($("input[name=number]").val());i++) {
  
    $("<label/>").attr({ class: 'label',id: 'lb'+i}).text(' Payment Date').appendTo("#pays");
                $("<input/>").attr({ type: 'text', id: 'paymentNo-'+(i), class: 'date input', name: 'payD[]', required: 'true' }).appendTo("#pays");
                
  }
  $(".date").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      onSelect: function(date) {
        $(this).parent().find(".date").datepicker({
          defaultDate: date,
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
        });
      }
    });
  });
 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
  <div id="pays">
    <label> How many? </label>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="pnumber">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm generating input fields dynamically based on user input and initializing date picker on them. Also, I'm trying to set default date to previously selected date in the dynamically generated field. The problem is, if I initialize datepicker with the option specified like in the code, the default date doesnt go to previously selected date but to current date also changing months and years  is not working. But if I give options after initialization like

```
$(this).parent().find(".date").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', date);
```

everything works as desired.

Please someone let me know why datepicker works this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... let me know why datepicker works this way.

So your question is **why** is it working differently when passing an object holding all the options we would like to set *(code chunk #1)* **or** passing 3 arguments, coma separated *(code chunk #2)*.

Code chunk #1:

```
$(element).datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date) { // some function here },
  defaultDate: date,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
```

Code chunk #2:

```
$(element).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', date);
```

**The difference:** #1 is the initialisation of an instance and #2 is the modification of a particular property of an existing instance.

Now, I think that *«what is an instance»* is a question that is quite out of SO scope... But I found an insteresting YouTube video you may watch [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNh013pa70E).

The [API documentation for DatePicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) lists all the options that you can initialise, get and set. The methods you can apply on an instance also are listed there.

Comment: Well, I don't want to disable previous dates just to maintain order. I'm trying to do it just for convenience so that I don't have click next to go to previously selected date. Also, your answer doesn't address my question, why doesn't datepicker take options given like above in my code.

Comment: Sorry, if I misread your question the first time... I edited.